# CSS: Absolute positioned image - but it's not on top

Tags: css, css-position, ribbon

I'm trying to position a ribbon image on one of my websites. Unfortunately I can't figure out why it doesn't work as I want it to. I used `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` to do all the positioning stuff but the problem is that the image is not on top:

[image: Ribbon]

I've used to following code:

```
.ribbon { position: relative; }
.ribbon h3 {
    background: url("images/ribbon.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Tahoma,arial,serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 7px 0 0 17px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -36px;
    width: 244px;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

If you want to take a look at the website you can do it [on this link](http://www.praxis-korbach.de) (user: ***tmp*** / pass: ***tmpuser***).

It should look like this:

[image: Ribbon]

Comment: The link gives a 404 error ("Oops! The Page Can Not Be Found!").

Comment: Is the screenshot what you want it to look like or how it's coming out?

Comment: @Peter Of The Corn: The link works for me, but please try [this one](http://www.praxis-korbach.de/) instead (same user/pass).

Comment: @Dennis - Getting a "No Pages Found" error message on both links

Comment: Very strange, no problems over here accessing the website.

Comment: @Anthony: I've added an image to my question with an image what it should look like. I hope it helps!

Comment: Does the parent container have overflow:hidden assigned to it? I had a different issue with the link you supplied - I was able to enter the username and password but then I got a warning of malicious content etc. Might be best if you put up a sample of your HTML and CSS up on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Dan: You're right. There was a parent container with overflow:hidden. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the outer DIV width is too small to fit all and it's pushing the image down.

Try setting up the width of the main / wrapping DIV to a larger width and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you but its pretty gnarley.

```
 .ribbon { 
   position: relative;
   height: 34px;
   width: 264px;
   padding: 7px 0 0 17px;
}

.ribbon h3 {
    background: url("images/ribbon.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Tahoma,arial,serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    height: 34px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 200;
}
```